# What's the etymology for the term "greensheet"?

Tags: etymology, american-english, north-american-english

I've been looking for the etymology of the word *greensheet*, specifically when used in the context of academia.

I know it's just another way to say "syllabus",  but where did the "green" in greentext come from? I've searched Google multiple times using different keywords, including *greensheet word etymology*, *origins of greensheet word*, *where does the word greensheet come from* but am having no luck at all.

In the U.S., the greensheet is the syllabus all college professors will give out or ask students to take note of in the first few days of classes.

Comment: from the old wet-copying machines perhaps?

Comment: OED does not contain a reference to *green text, greensheet* or *green sheet*.

Comment: @AndrewLeach https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=greensheet%20syllabus This is a fairly common term that many professors use to describe the syllabus for their class

Comment: I wasn't saying it wasn't used; I was commenting that OED didn't record its use. It is notable that the top 40 links in that Google search [I didn't look any further] are all American.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Should I tag it as US or american now or something?

Comment: I don't think this is a widely-understood reference.  But in certain contexts different colors of paper have attained meaning.  "Pink sheet" is probably the only generally understood such term in the US.  Some grade schools in the US used to use "pinks and blues" for the student enrollment cards sent to teachers.  "Peach" has a meaning within IBM (which I can't recall just now).  "Green sheet" many refer to the fact that some bookkeeping ledgers contained light-green tinted paper, though it's not clear how that would connect to "syllabus".

Comment: I'd not heard the term, and suspected it was something local to an institution, but a Google search on "greensheet syllabus" turns up numerous results from universities and school districts all over the U.S. We did have *bluebooks* for examinations, but not being a big sports school, no *redshirts*.

Comment: @choster I was thinking maybe greensheet has to do with green somewhat meaning "new" or "fresh", but I wanted to be really sure where this term came from. Thanks for the bounty!

Comment: Clumsy idea, but may it just have to do something with green light? A syllabus tells you, among other things, what you have to know in order to pass, am I not right?

Comment: I wonder if a green "blackboard" would be relevant. Listing of Syllabus on a green chalkboard transcribed on paper.

Comment: Speaking as an American university professor of linguistics and English of 50 years experience, I can state that (a) I have never used the term _green sheet_, with or without space, to refer to class syllabi or handouts; (b) I have never heard any other American university professor use it that way, either. And I know a lot of American university professors. So it sounds like it's more localized than just "American". Probly some school, or group of schools, used green paper once and the name stuck, at least regionally.

Comment: Back in the days when a US stock could not trade even on the curb, it might be a pink- sheet stock, because quotes of such stocks were published weekly -oh you guessed- on pink sheets .If I remember correctly,  quotes of bonds that were of comparable low quality were published weekly on yellow sheets, but such bonds were just called junk bonds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did a bit of a deep web crawl on this, as I've never heard a syllabus called a greensheet. This made me curious as to whether it might be regional.

I saw several uses of the word as a replacement for syllabus (often with syllabus in parenthesis as well). Several of these uses were as old as 2006. I decided to limit my search to anything *before* 2006 and found a single web page discussing the use of the word greensheet as a synonym for syllabus: http://www.sjsu.edu/faculty/watkins/style.htm. The purpose of the page isn't even to explain the word (it's all about style sheets and only mentions why a syllabus is called a greensheet in passing).

I hit a dead end after this discovery. However, that explanation could very well be the answer. Consider: I went to school on the east coast (at three different schools) and never heard a syllabus called a greensheet. SJSU is on the west coast and uses the term greensheet to refer to a syllabus. Proposition: The word greensheet started either *at* SJSU or, at least, in that geographical area because the syllabi were/are printed on green paper.

Answer (score 2):

I've never run across an academic use of *greensheet* and wonder what it means thee.

Brokerage houses distribute information about new issues to their associates, describing the security, and its merits and drawbacks, so they can do a good job of foisting it on investors.  Because the information is about *green* (immature) investments, and it's printed on paper, it's a greensheet.

A syllabus is also a sales document, if you think about it, and often the course taught was somewhat difference that what was planned in the syllabus, so it may be that they borrowed the terminology of another enterprise that also markets overpriced dreams to the gullible.

Comment: Well that escalated quickly.

Answer (score 1):

I attended four different US undergrad schools, a US law school, and a Chinese economics school's master of laws program, and I have never heard of a greensheet. Like other commentators, however, I found that the Google God declares it is The Truth.

First, an Ngram:

[image: Ngram of greensheet]

I did not include before 1920 because there were zero uses before then.

### Blackboard software

Many colleges use a program called [Blackboard](http://www.blackboard.com/), and [Google Fu suggests](https://www.google.com.mx/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1ASAB_enUS601MX610&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=green%20text%20used%20as%20a%20placeholder%20syllabus) that the "Syllabus Template" uses green text as a "placeholder" to tell the instructor to replace all of the green text. But, to jump from green text to greensheet is difficult to believe.

### Bureaucracy

At Kutztown University of Pennsylvania, each instructor must give their syllabus to the administration and the syllabus must be color-coded based on department. [Green is for the College of Business.](http://www.kutztown.edu/gened/comp_app.html) I doubt that green is related to business schools, however, because most other uses do not seem connected to a department, see for example, [Foothill Handbook](http://www.foothill.edu/staff/documents/Faculty_Handbook.pdf). Nevertheless, it is possible that some long-forgotten bureaucratic decision requiring syllabi to be on green paper spawned this idiom.

### Good luck!

It seems that greensheet is only used at a few institutions, so that makes it unlikely that some random person on Stack Exchange will know the answer. The Ngram suggests that the usage of the term is fairly new, however, so if someone were truly industrious, there are likely many people still alive who could help discover the origin.

Comment: Nice answer, but the Ngram shows up as a blank image for me, any fix?

Comment: Maybe this link https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=greensheet&year_start=1920&year_end=2015&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgreensheet%3B%2Cc0